# I want to implement dual tree complex wavelet transform (DTCWT) for image processing

Tags: matlab, wavelet

Iwant to implement dual tree complex wavelet transform . I  have tried with the matlab function dddtree as follows

```
dwt1 = dddtree('dwt',x ,J,'db2') ; 
dwt1Cfs_train(k,:) = dwt1.cfs{J};      
dt1 = dddtree('cplxdt',x,J,'dtf3');  
dt1Cfs = dt1.cfs{J}(:,:,1)+1i*dt1.cfs{J}(:,:,2);
```

variable 'x' is a 60*60 pixel image
I did this for 3220 train image 
where I stored the value of 'dt1Cfs' as 3220*15 matrix

But when I used this for the classification I am not getting the correct result . I am not sure how to use it for feature extraction. Can anybody help me

I have implemented Feature extraction using  Wavelets using  dwt2 function, and I was able to do the feature extraction properly

```
dwt1 = dddtree('dwt',x ,J,'db2') ; 
dwt1Cfs_train(k,:) = dwt1.cfs{J};      
dt1 = dddtree('cplxdt',x,J,'dtf3');  
dt1Cfs = dt1.cfs{J}(:,:,1)+1i*dt1.cfs{J}(:,:,2);
```

variable 'x' is a 60*60 pixel image
I did this for 3220 train image 
where I stored the value of 'dt1Cfs' as 3220*15 matrix

I need to extracted features using DTCWT so that later I can do classification

Answer (score 0):

Ask [this man](http://www-sigproc.eng.cam.ac.uk/Main/NGK#JumpMaterials)... His webpage is full of useful scripts.